# В чём ошибка sql запроса?

Tags: mysql, sql

Хочу из БД вытащить инфу по датам, но возвращается Warning: #1411 Incorrect datetime value

```
select GT.NAME as АЙДИ,
       TT.PROPERTY_54 as Состав,
       TT.PROPERTY_44 as Стоимость,
       TT.PROPERTY_47 as СтоимостьДоставки,
       TT.PROPERTY_73 as ДатаДоставки,
       TT.PROPERTY_74 as ВремяДоставки,
       TT.PROPERTY_60 as ИмяПокупателя,
       TT.PROPERTY_67 as ИмяПолучателя,
       TT.PROPERTY_61 as ТелефонПокупателя,
       TT.PROPERTY_69 as НомерПолучателя,
       TT.PROPERTY_62 as Email,
       TT.PROPERTY_71 as АдресДоставки,
       TT.PROPERTY_75 as ВремяДоставки
from b_iblock_element_prop_s10 as TT
left join b_iblock_element as GT ON GT.ID = TT.PROPERTY_53
where TT.PROPERTY_59 BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('‎2020-05-12 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') 
  AND STR_TO_DATE('‎2020-11-12 23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

В ваших датах присутствуют непечатные символы:

```sh
$ hexdump -C <<< '‎2020-05-12 00:00:00'
00000000  e2 80 8e 32 30 32 30 2d  30 35 2d 31 32 20 30 30  |...2020-05-12 00|
00000010  3a 30 30 3a 30 30 0a                              |:00:00.|
```

Избавьтесь от них и всё станёт ок:  [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com#!9/9eecb/182774)

Answer (score 0):

Вот что нашёл на английской ветке

> SELECT STR_TO_DATE("'2015-05-15 15:57:46'", "'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'")
> Your current statement is the following, and since the pattern doesn't match you are >getting NULL:
>
> SELECT STR_TO_DATE("'2015-05-15 15:57:46'", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')

Похоже просто забыли доставить кавычки ""
Перевод на вскидку такой: "Ваш текущий оператор следующий, и поскольку шаблон не соответствует, вы получаете NULL"

Answer (score 0):

Конвертация STR_TO_DATE совершенно излишня. MySQL отлично сравинивает даты со строками:

```
select GT.NAME as АЙДИ,
       TT.PROPERTY_54 as Состав,
       TT.PROPERTY_44 as Стоимость,
       TT.PROPERTY_47 as СтоимостьДоставки,
       TT.PROPERTY_73 as ДатаДоставки,
       TT.PROPERTY_74 as ВремяДоставки,
       TT.PROPERTY_60 as ИмяПокупателя,
       TT.PROPERTY_67 as ИмяПолучателя,
       TT.PROPERTY_61 as ТелефонПокупателя,
       TT.PROPERTY_69 as НомерПолучателя,
       TT.PROPERTY_62 as Email,
       TT.PROPERTY_71 as АдресДоставки,
       TT.PROPERTY_75 as ВремяДоставки
from b_iblock_element_prop_s10 as TT
left join b_iblock_element as GT ON GT.ID = TT.PROPERTY_53
where TT.PROPERTY_59 BETWEEN '‎2020-05-12 00:00:00' AND '‎2020-11-12 23:59:59'
```

;